# changing TYPO3 realurl language urls

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x, realurl

I'm using TYPO3 7.6.11 and realurl 2.0.15

my translated versions got this url:

```
http://url.de/3/services
```

is there a way to replace the 3 with the language code? for 3 it should be *en* for example?

thanks a lot

Comment: Just FYI: it is not "real url" but "reaurl". You will not like your name spelled as "Fe Lix", right? :) Please, make sure you spell the name correctly next time. Do some respect for the developer. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the 'preVars' configuration array for your languages to realurl.
It is straigtly described in the manual:
[Realurl manual - language example config deep-link](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/realurl/Realurl/Configuration/ConfigurationDirectives/Index.html#id47)

Excerpt/Example:

```
    $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['EXTCONF'] ['realurl'] ['_DEFAULT'] ['preVars'] => array(
                array(
                    'GETvar' => 'L',
                    'valueMap' => array(
                        'de' => '0',
                        'en' => '1',
                        ),
                    'valueDefault' => 'de',
                    # 'noMatch' => 'bypass',
                ),
);
```

Alternatively you could just use the 'automatic configuration' shipped with realurl. AFAIR it usually adds also lang-configs.
The Auto-Conf feature is to be enabled via Extension-Manager.

Comment: Just be careful because this manual is for realurl 1.x and some options are not valid for realurl 2.x.

Comment: Thank you for clarification, but:
So you tell me, that the link to the official manual at docs.typo3.org is an old/outdated manual? Good to know, but IMHO just bad ... not only because the 'extension manual' link in the repository is just wrong/outdated, but much more because the extension then is also shipped with an outdated manual ...

Comment: Yes, that's right. The manual is for the obsolete TYPO3 version. All information about version 2.x is here: https://github.com/dmitryd/typo3-realurl/wiki

The reason: earlier manuals could be edited with LibreOffice. Now there is some kind of obscure text format, which I neither have time to learn, nor wish. Thuse the manual is only on the wiki.

Answer (score 2):

Please, see how to set up languages correctly: https://github.com/dmitryd/typo3-realurl/wiki/Notes-for-Integrators#configuring-languages There are instructions and examples there.